# How to modify an html file with a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm now to coding so sorry if my question is dumb. I'm trying to code an extension getting information from the html of some websites, and then display the info I got on the popup of the extension. The problem is, when I can't communicate between the foreground.js and the html of the popup.
Here is the popup file,

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>`
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
            justify-content: last baseline;
            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Welcome to LISTOKADO</h2>
    <a href="https://www.listokado.com/" title="lien html">
        <img alt="listokado" src="./logoListo-2.png" width="64" height="64" />
    </a>
    <a>
        <img alt= 'Choisissez un article'id="imgAchatEnCours" src="" width="64" height="64">
    </a>
    <p> <input type="submit" value="Add to wishlist" />
    </p>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="im_achat.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here the foreground.js :

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('a-offscreen')['6'].innerText)
console.log(document.querySelector('#productTitle').textContent)

var img_achat = new Image
img_achat = document.querySelector('#imgTagWrapperId img').src
localStorage.setItem('img_achat_en_cours',img_achat)
console.log('im chargée dans le localstorage')
//document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
     const recentImageDataUrl = localStorage.getItem("img_achat_en_cours")
     console.log(recentImageDataUrl);

     if(recentImageDataUrl){
      //console.log('test allo')
        Document.getElementById('#imgAchatEnCours').setAttribute("src",recentImageDataUrl)
        console.log('si ça saffiche cest que cest bon');
     }
//});
```

How can I modify the src of the image 'imgAchatEnCours' in the html of the popup? is there an equivalent to Document.getElementById() like popup.getelement() or something? Because I understood that I'm searching in the web page so I don't modify what i want

Thank you for reading

Comment: Try to change `Document.getElementById('#imgAchatEnCours').setAttribute("src",recentImageDataUrl)` to `Document.getElementById('#imgAchatEnCours').src = recentImageDataUrl;`

Comment: The problem is that the program is searching for #imgAchatEnCours in the document, here the website . I'm trying to make it understand that i want to modify something in the popup.html
It's currrently not finding the element because it's not looking at the right file